# Proof of the following derivate results

Tags: optics, differentiation, mathematics

Anyone can help me proving the following

If x'=sx where s is a constant then

(d/dx') = (1/s)(d/dx)

Comment: This is a math question. It doesn’t involve any physics.

Answer (score 2):

We have $$x^\prime=sx.$$
Thus, $$dx^\prime=sdx\implies\frac{dx}{dx^\prime}=\frac{1}{s}$$

Apply chain rule of derivative. For a test function $f$,

$$\frac{df(x)}{dx^\prime}=\frac{df(x)}{dx}\frac{dx}{dx^\prime}=\frac{1}{s}\frac{df(x)}{dx}$$.

As the function is arbitrary, the operator relation is then,

$$\frac{d}{dx^\prime}=\frac{1}{s}\frac{d}{dx}$$

Comment: Vacuum Thank for the help, I just have one doubt remaining. How did you pass from dx'=s dx to (dx/dx')=1/s, I mean we can't treat the differentials (dx) as normal variables.

Comment: @Who Think of it like this: you have $x^\prime=s x\implies x=\frac{1}{s}x^\prime$. Now take derivative on both sides with $x^\prime$, that is, $\frac{d}{dx^\prime}\left(x=\frac{1}{s} x^\prime\right)\implies \frac{dx}{dx^\prime}=\frac{1}{s}$.

Comment: Thanks, that makes much more sense